# PostgreSQL Full Text Search with substrings

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to create the fastest way to search millions (80+ mio) of records in a PostgreSQL (version 9.4), over multiple columns.

I would like to try and use standard PostgreSQL, and not Solr etc.

I'm currently testing Full Text Search followed https://blog.lateral.io/2015/05/full-text-search-in-milliseconds-with-postgresql/.

It works, but I would like some more flexible way to search.

Currently, if I have a column containing ex. "Volvo" and one containing "Blue" I am able to find the record with the search string "volvo blue", but I would like to also find the record using "volvo blu" as if I used LIKE and "%blu%'.

Is that possible with full text search?

Comment: FTS has prefix matching facilities, but in general it is not designed to do that efficiently. FTS is designed around finding lexeme matches (and `blu` vs. `blue` is not a match, but f.ex. `volvo`, `volvos` and `volvo's` are). -- If you can upgrade to 9.6, the `pg_trgm` has a nice new feature in it: word similarity, which might handle your use cases.

Comment: 9.6 also added support for "phrase search" (multiple adjacent words) in FTS.

Comment: Or, for an alternative solution, you could do the search in 2 steps: 1st, you need to search for each word's typos (`pg_trgm` is especially good in it). After you found matches, you can offer your end-users the possibility to search for those instead in a 2nd step (similarly f.ex. how google handles when you misspell words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option to something like this is by using the [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) contrib module.

This enables you to create a GIN or GiST index that indexes all sequences of three characters, which can be used for a search with the similarity operator `%`.

Two notes:

1. Using the `%` operator may return “false positive” results, so be sure to add a second condition (e.g. with `LIKE`) that eliminates those.
2. A trigram search works well with longer search strings, but performs badly with short search strings because of the many false positive results.

If that is not good enough for your purposes, you'll have to resort to an third-party solution.

Comment: Their examples primarely shows searching for only one word in one column. How can I search for multiple words in multiple columns?

Comment: You can either use a single `%` operator on concatenated columns (`col1 || ' ' || col2 % 'searchstring'`) or use several `%` comparisons joined with `AND` (`col1 % 'searchstring' AND col2 % 'searchstring'`).